# SSRS Conditional Formating Where There's NULL

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a report with the number of attendees by month shown and rows grouped on an "Attended" or "Did Not Attend" `Attendance_Indicator` flag (this in itself is a sub-group of a higher level of grouping).

For legibility I wanted any row of Attended data with a coloured background (say LightGrey) and any other rows transparent.

I have highlighted the cells within the table at this grouping level and used the expression below:

```
=IIF(Fields!Attendance_Indicator.Value = "Attended","LightGrey","Transparent")
```

This partial works in that where the count of attendees is >0 the cells' background colour changes to grey. However, in cells where the count of attendees is 0 the background remains transparent.

Can anyone advise how I can get any cells, whatever the count value, on the Attended row to change background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[IsNothing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157328.aspx) is your friend here. You may need to fiddle with the logic for your colours (e.g. NOT IsNothing rather than IsNothing)... but you get the idea.

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!Attendance_Indicator.Value)  OR Fields!Attendance_Indicator.Value)  = "Attended","LightGrey","Transparent")
```

Comment: Thank you for your input but this throws the following error when the report fails to preview           'The BackgroundColor expression for the text box ‘Textbox20’ contains an error: [BC30057] Too many arguments to 'Public Function IsNothing(Expression As Object) As Boolean'. (rsCompilerErrorInExpression)'

Comment: My fault - I've changed the sample - sorry!

Comment: Many thanks for your kind assistance.  From initial testing it provides the desired result.  In case anyone else has a similar requirement I did have to modify it slightly by removing the 'close bracket' just before the equals sign.  Initially I thought that the OR statement might need bracketing so added a bracket just before the Ifnothing.  However, in that case no grey backgrounds were applied at all but removing the 'close bracket' gave the correct result.       Once again thank you.